# Should I be using a Welch or standard T-test?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I'm really confused here. I am trying to compare two sets of data which differ in sample size. One has 257 entries and the other has 598. They are measures of scores on two different assessment types where the only possible scores are 1 through 4, with half points allowed. The means are a half point different, the standard deviations are .2 different, and the skews are different. I'm positive that the difference is significant.

What test can I use to prove that the difference is significant? I think it's a 2 tailed, independent t-test, but apparently a Welch's test is used when the sample sizes are different? The answer to this is probably very simple, but I've spent enough time trying to figure this out that I'm more confused than when I started.

Comment: I ran it as this in excel: T.TEST(A2:A258, C2:C599, 2, 3) and it gave me a very low p (8.46422E-21). This seems right, but I'm still not sure if it's the right test.

Comment: It is often better to generalize the question to ask if a randomly selected observation from A tends to be larger than a randomly selected observation from B.  This is the essence of the highly efficient and robust Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney two-sample rank test.

Comment: If you are using a $t$ test, you should use the Welch-Satterthwaite adjustment if you aren't already quite confident that the population variances are going to be very close to equal. When dealing with bounded, skew and highly-discrete variables (such as you have), both that and the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney have problems and there's often not a lot to choose between them. Large samples (as you have) tend to reduce the problems, but the WMW must be adjusted for the heavy ties (a decent package should be able to this)

Comment: Just to add to what has already been said:  since it is unlikely that the scores are drawn from a normal distribution, either $t$ test may not be appropriate.  The independent $t$-test doesn't require equal sample sizes: it does require an assumption that the population variance is equal between the two groups.  If this is not the case, the Welch $t$-test is appropriate.  The nonparametric Wilcoxon rank test, with correction for ties, would be another choice, and this is the approach I would use at first glance, but it may not have enough power.